# Mac OS update password for "Local Item" Keychain

Tags: keychain

I use mobile network logins for Mac books. The issue is when they are required to change there network password it does not update the password for the "Local Items" keychain. I can clear out the keychain files but all I want to do is update the password to the new password but the option is greyed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. By doing a key chain repair on the "Login" Key chain then locking and unlocking the both the "Login" and "Local Items" key chain. Gave me a prompt for the old password on the "Local Items" It then asked me to update the password for the "Local Items" Key chain. Allowing me to finaly change the password. I then set the password to the new network login password and everything is working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

I just followed this guide:
https://techraptor.net/content/iron-mac-how-to-get-rid-of-annoying-local-items-keychain-box

**TL;DR**

1. Delete the folder you find inside `~/Library/Keychains/`
2. Restart your mac
3. Enjoy

Worked for me!

Comment: OP found already the solution

Comment: Yep, I tried that, but it didn't work for me. So I thought sharing is caring. :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a difference between the 'local items' and the 'login' keychain, then locking the 'login' keychain and then unlocking it will bring up the 'new password' dialogue box as well, no need to do a chain repair first. Make sure both of them are the same as the password on the user account and that would be the end of the pop up boxes asking you for the password.

On a side note, keep a close eye on the app asking for the password, if you want to go fast it might look like you're typing in the wrong password, while all your doing is clearing one with the correct password and getting the next one in queue. When getting the boxes, first open up keychain, unlock both of them and then cancel all the dialogue boxes...